# How to write generic Code to save and edit model in C#?

Tags: c#

Here, I am trying to save and edit the model for which is do below code. But I want to develop generic code which can do the same work for any model passed.
Below is my code

```
public void SaveGallery(Video model)
    {
        if (model.VideoId == 0)
        {
            uow.Repository<Video>().Add(model);
        }
        else
        {
            uow.Repository<Video>().Edit(model);
        }
        uow.Commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

With my discomfort of *Repositories* put aside. You could use *generics* and a `Func`

```
public void AddOrUpdateStuff<T>(T model, Func<T,int> id)
{
   if (id(model) == 0)
      uow.Repository<T>().Add(model);
   else
      uow.Repository<T>().Edit(model);
   uow.Commit();
}
```

**Usage**

```
AddOrUpdateStuff(something, s => s.Id);
```

Also you could probably make this an *Extension Method* however it would be best to *constrain* it to an *interface* or a *base type*

A better solution would be consistent naming of your Ids in an *Interface*

```
public Interface IModel
{
    int Id {get;set;}
}
```

and your signature could look like this with more typed goodness

```
public void AddOrUpdateStuff<T>(this T model) where T : IModel
{
   if (model.Id == 0)
      uow.Repository<T>().Add(model);
   else
      uow.Repository<T>().Edit(model);
   uow.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Repositories aside ;) I'd prefer the functional approach. Enforcing this with an interface that defines a single method is a great use case for a function; similar to when you take ISP to its logical conclusion.